# Run command in cron

Tags: cron

I'm trying to execute the command "redshift -l 33.8683:151.2086" at boot on my ubuntu system. The program works when run in a terminal so it may be sensitive to having the right runtime level. I've tried adding the command to a file in /usr/sbin and adding /usb/sbin/redshift1 to my /etc/rc.local, but it does not execute properly. The location of the actual script is in /usr/bin/ but I want to start the program with the arguments I mentioned. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want redshift to start after you started your desktop environment. You can either open "Startup Application" or similar depending on desktop environment, press add and add the command you attached in the command field.

You can also create the file ~/.config/autostart/redshift.desktop and enter

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Redshift
GenericName=Redshift
Comment=
Exec=redshift -l 33.8683:151.2086
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=none
Categories=
StartupNotify=false
```